# Hibernate - how to sort by first element's property in a oneToMany Collection

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

Using Spring Data JPA and a HQL query, I would like to sort my objects by some timestamp property in a oneToMany property.

Given the query

```
select distinct t from Transport t 
join fetch t.waypoints wp
```

I would like to do something like (invalid syntax)

```
select distinct t from Transport t 
join fetch t.waypoints wp  
order by t.waypoints[0].someTimeStamp
```

Is there an (relatively) easy way to do this in hql? Because if not, it is probably easier to sort the result in Java (since in my case the list does not contain many elements, it's not a big deal)

I have tried something like (there is an order property in Waypoint)

```
select distinct t,wp2 from Transport t 
join fetch t.waypoints wp inner join t.waypoints wp2 
where t.id in :ids and wp2.order = 0 
order by wp2.someTimeStamp
```

But then, the results are multiplied. If a transport has n waypoints, it appears n times in the result list...

classes:

```
public class Transport {

    @Id
    private UUID id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "transport")
    @OrderBy("order_ asc")
    private Set<Waypoint> waypoints = new LinkedHashSet<>();

}

@Entity
public class Waypoint {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "transport_id")
    private Transport transport;

    @Column(name = "order_")
    private Integer order;

    private Instant someTimeStamp;

}
```

Comment: Where is your entity class ?

Comment: I have added them, but basically a simple entity with a OneToMany property

Comment: Try removing  `ASC` from  `@OrderBy("order_")`